# Error when running Code coverage in Visual studio using Chutzpah

Tags: chutzpah

Trying to run the code coverage in Visual studio using Chutzpah, but getting the below error.

```
Log Message: waiting for blanket... from     
C:\Users\gorulra\Desktop\Raja\FrontEndTools\FrontEndTools.WebUI.Scripts.Test\Tests123\Services\dataService.spec.js 
Error: Error: Instrumentation error, you cannot redefine the 'window' variable in file:///C:/Users/gorulra/Desktop/Raja/FrontEndTools/FrontEndTools.WebUI.Scripts.Test/Scripts/vendor/js/angular.js:996 in file:///C:/Users/gorulra/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/diby4xuj.1y3/TestFiles/Coverage/blanket_jasmine_v2.js (line 4253)
While Running:C:\Users\gorulra\Desktop\Raja\FrontEndTools\FrontEndTools.WebUI.Scripts.Test\Tests123\Services\dataService.spec.js Error: Error: error loading source script in file:///C:/Users/gorulra/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/diby4xuj.1y3/TestFiles/Coverage/blanket_jasmine_v2.js (line 5141) While Running:C:\Users\gorulra\Desktop\Raja\FrontEndTools\FrontEndTools.WebUI.Scripts.Test\Tests123\Services\dataService.spec.js 
Error: Timeout occurred when executing test file While Running:C:\Users\gorulra\Desktop\Raja\FrontEndTools\FrontEndTools.WebUI.Scripts.Test\Tests123\Services\dataService.spec.js
========== Total Tests: 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 total ==========
```

Answer (score 7):

This is due to an error in `blanket.js`. See [issue](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/issues/311) for a discussion.

The suggested workaround is to reference the minified version of `angular.js`, which will resolved the 'window' redefine issue and allow you to run the code coverage in chutzpah.